# SQL Server outer apply causing major CPU burden

Tags: sql, sql-server, outer-join, coalesce

I have a user view which I've created in sql with an outer apply which brings back the amount of years experience the user has according to their employment records.

When I monitored the cost of my SQL statements in Activity monitor (SQL Enterprise manager) it says that this part in the view is causing 25% of a rather large CPU cost in the execution plan.

I'm trying to work out a more effecient way of bringing this metric into the view without the additional overhead.

HERE is the apply...

```
SELECT *
FROM users U <BLAH BLAH BLAH> OUTER apply
  (SELECT COALESCE (Year(Getdate()) - Min(StartYear), 0) AS YearsWorkExp
   FROM dbo.job_history
   WHERE (userid = U.userid)) AS WorkExp
```

Comment: in any case, are you actually selecting and therefore joining multiple records in the query inside the OUTER APPLY - you are no applying any grouping - will job_history (potentially) have multiple records for each employee?

Comment: You need outer apply for the function calls, when not using functions you can use joins.

Answer (score 0):

Untested but have a go at something like this:

```
;WITH base AS
(
  SELECT 
      userid,
      MIN(StartYear) StartYear
  FROM dbo.job_history
  GROUP BY userid
)    
SELECT u.*
     , YEAR(GETDATE()) - ISNULL(b.StartYear, YEAR(Getdate()))  AS YearsWorkExp
FROM   users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN base b
ON b.userid = u.userid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing an index on the `job_history` table (`userid, StartYear`)

```
create index idx_job_history_userid_StartYear on dbo.job_history (userid, StartYear)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, i might be missing something, but,  you seem to be calculating work experience for every year he has been there (actually the work experience returned n times I think), and then joining to every record, maybe if you just want the work experience now

```
    SELECT *
FROM users U <BLAH BLAH BLAH> OUTER apply
  (SELECT TOP 1 COALESCE (Year(Getdate()) - StartYear, 0) AS YearsWorkExp
   FROM dbo.job_history
   WHERE (userid = U.userid) ORDER BY StartYear DESC) AS WorkExp
```

how many records would  the
SELECT COALESCE (Year(Getdate()) - Min(StartYear), 0) AS YearsWorkExp
   FROM dbo.job_history
   WHERE (userid = U.userid)

be designed to return, and therefore join to?   Do you see what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using same Year value to calculate Years of experience, then why not calculate it before instead of calling function `YEAR()` and `GETDATE()` for each row in `OUTER APPLY`

```
DECLARE @Yr INT = Year(Getdate());
SELECT *
FROM users U <BLAH BLAH BLAH> 
OUTER apply
(
    SELECT COALESCE (@Yr - Min(StartYear), 0) AS YearsWorkExp
    FROM dbo.job_history
    WHERE (userid = U.userid)
) AS WorkExp
```

Answer (score 0):

The overhead is in the COALESCE function,  use ISNULL function instead 
ISNULL (@Yr - Min(StartYear), 0) AS YearsWorkExp

Comment: ISNULL has a minor performance advantage. Changing COALESCE to ISNULL isn't going to be the savior here.